# Artificial Intelligence and Chat Filters

Tags: filter, artificial-intelligence, nlp, chat

Are there any chat filters that works depending on the context? I'm talking about the use of new technologies like Artificial Intelligence and Natural Language Processing to determine for example if a word was rude or not, **depending on the context**.

Comment: Censorship is [bullshit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullshit).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to just use a regex for the handful of most offensive words.

There are services offered online that will allow you to query with a word to see if it's profane. Those are good options if you want to be really sure.

Unfortunately, there's no sure bet for any of these. One man's profanity is another's common talk (see santorum. very very vulgar, but most aren't offended.) And each group has their own fowl language. ballox isn't so bad in America, but it's fairly bad in Britain.

You could make a clbuttic mistake. Even if you eliminate everything, I can still write a horribly offensive story using the kindest language.

A short black list or one of the services is the way to go depending on the level of filtering you want.

Comment: @TTT: this is a very difficult problem. **There is no solution** as there is no defined set of language that cannot be offensive to at least one person.

Answer (score 0):

This looks interesting http://pottymouthfilter.com, It is unfortunately commercial product but at least someone is working on something along those lines.